# NOT_FOUND: Invalid resource ID when calling Custom Google Cloud ML Model From Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, machine-learning, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-automl

I'm calling a GCP Custom ML Model from a node.js firebase function. But when I call the `predict` function, I get an Error 5: NOT_FOUND: Invalid resource ID
I've turned on the ML API and I've checked the format of the model name, it looks to be correct according to the docs: projects//locations/us-central1/models/

My code looks like:

```
// Create client for prediction service.
const client = new automl.PredictionServiceClient();

const projectId = 'project-id';
const computeRegion = 'us-central1';
const modelId = 'model-name';

// Get the full path of the model.
const modelFullId = client.modelPath(projectId, computeRegion, modelId);

const params = {};
const payload = {};
payload.instances = {"data1": 38.0,
                     "data2": -2.7,
                     "data3": -0.4,
                     "data4": 2.1,
                     "data5": -2.7,
                     "data6": -1.7,
                     "data7": 0.4,
                     "data8": 8.5,
                     "data9": -1.1,
                     "data10": 0.2
                    };

const [response] = await client.predict({
                        name: modelFullId,
                        payload: payload,
                        params: params,
                    });
console.log(`Prediction results:`);
response.payload.forEach(result => {
    console.log(`Predicted class name: ${result.displayName}`);
    console.log(`Predicted class score: ${result.classification.score}`);
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: It seems to me that maybe you are not using the right value for modelId. Remember that has to be of the form `const modelId = ID of the model, e.g. “ICN723541179344731436” ;` not the model-name e.g. `"flowers_test_v203"`.  [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/models#list-models) to see your models and their IDs.

Comment: @aemon4 thank you for your comment. I have tried running that code to show the models and IDs. Interestingly I get nothing back, no error, just an empty array. I have 3 models in my project.